# How to close responsive Hamburger menu via link using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kinda stuck at a roadblock so I figured I come here for some advice.

I'm helping my classmate integrate an embed code into their Carrd site. We got this menu working pretty well but there's 1 feature we can't figure out.

We're trying to close the responsive hamburger via JS but we're not sure what to do. The goal is to close the menu once a link is clicked.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

```
<style>
body {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
padding: 30px;
}
nav ul {
float: right;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
margin-left: 25px;
}
nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
color: #808080;
text-decoration: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
.nav-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
background: #1f2227;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.nav-container ul {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
width: 100%;
}
.nav-container ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-container ul li:nth-child(1) a {
transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.nav-container ul li:nth-child(2) a {
transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.nav-container ul li:nth-child(3) a {
transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.nav-container ul li:nth-child(4) a {
transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-container ul li a {
padding: 10px 25px;
opacity: 0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 600;
transform: translateY(-20px);
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.nav-open {
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
display: block;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 9999;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.nav-open i {
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 2px;
background: #1f2227;
border-radius: 2px;
margin-left: 14px;
}
.nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
margin-top: 16px;
}
.nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
margin-top: 4px;
opacity: 1;
}
.nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
margin-top: 4px;
}
}
#nav:checked + .nav-open {
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav:checked + .nav-open i {
background: #fff;
transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
#nav:checked + .nav-open i:nth-child(1) {
transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}
#nav:checked + .nav-open i:nth-child(2) {
opacity: 0;
}
#nav:checked + .nav-open i:nth-child(3) {
transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}
#nav:checked ~ .nav-container {
z-index: 9990;
opacity: 1;
}
#nav:checked ~ .nav-container ul li a {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0);
}
.hidden {
display: none;
}

.show{
    display:block;
}

</style>

<html>
<nav>
<input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden"/>
<label for="nav" class="nav-open"><i></i><i></i><i></i></label>
<div class="nav-container">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>


</html>
```

Comment: I would have tried to answer you but before that it would have asked me to waste time indenting your code to be able to study it serenely....

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a checkbox for the menu, it's as simple as unchecking the checkbox once a link is clicked.

```
document.querySelectorAll('li>a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked = false
  })
})
```

1, Select all the links inside the list with `querySelectorAll`
2, Loop through the links and add a click event listener for each link
3, Select the `input` tag which is the checkbox and set the `checked` property to false